# c# MongoDB RunCommand

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Can someone give me an example of the use of the RunCommand method  that takes a string argument only (called CommandName) available in the MongoDB .NET driver?  I know there is an overloaded RunCommand method that takes an object reference (I think a CommandDocument object) as an argument, but I'd rather not use that one.

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for CommandName.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some recent version of the official C# driver, the "real" `string` based version you are referring to (`CommandResult RunCommand(string commandName)`) is only part of the legacy driver component (check the namespace). I would hence not recommend using it.

The "official" interface currently looks like this:

```
TResult RunCommand<TResult>(Command<TResult> command, /* and some additional optional parameters */)
```

And since the C# driver heavily relies on implicit type conversions, there also is one from a `string` (and a `BsonDocument`) to the corresponding sub types of `Command<TResult>` (`JsonCommand<TResult>` and `BsonDocumentCommand<TResult>`). So you can effectively pass a `string` to the above new `RunCommand()` method, too.

You can therefore write either one of the following lines both of which do the exact same thing:

```
RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{count: \"collection_name\"}")
RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("count", "collection_name"))
```